# How to write socket codes via php

Tags: php, sockets, xampp, localhost

I wrote the follwing code in PHP

```
<?php
$mysocket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0);
socket_bind($mysocket, '127.0.0.1',1024);
socket_listen($mysocket) or die("unable to listen!");
socket_connect($mysocket , '127.0.0.1' , 1024);?>
```

and an error showed up says"

> Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [102]: Operation not supported on socket in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SOCKTEST.php on line 5"

Where is the problem?

Comment: Usually that error is because something is already bound to that address. Try a much higher port number, like `30000` as the lower port numbers are likely the ones already bound.

Comment: not working!,but keep in mind that I didn't install WebSocket on XAMPP think that's why the error shows up?

Comment: You shouldn't have to install anything if the PHP version is correct.

Comment: so why the error is shown up? :/

Comment: Good question. Without knowing more about your server configuration or being able to see the error logs it will be very hard to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the goal of your code. But here is a great tutorial for socket programming in PHP.

https://www.christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

I have tested your code. The error comes if your bind your socket to and address

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($sock, '127.0.0.1');
socket_connect($sock, '127.0.0.1', 1337);
socket_close($sock);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.socket-bind.php

Example from the PHP documentation. Perhaps its better if you use different instances to test your problem that you can connect through your network to another instance or computer. For this you can use vagrant for example.

Answer (score 0):

Servers listen and accept, clients connect. The same socket endpoint cannot be both a server (listen) and a client (connect)